AWS SES domain registration
I need little clarification. I want to send email from marketing.domain.com, my parent domain is domain.com.
I want to register the AWS domain identity which I have used. I have earlier used subdomain marketing.domain.com then AWS recommendation error message is that, Mail FROM is not align.
After that I re-registered domain identity, with domain.com and MAIL FROM using subdomain marketing.domain.com, in that case if bounced ratio are high then will AWS block our main domain for further sending email?
